# ReactJs - How can I add an 'active' class to the nav bar buttons depending on which page is currently being used?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, state, jsx

**I'm new to React**, after following numerous YouTube tutorials I still can't quite grasp how to go about this, I think it involves using "*states*" but every attempt has failed so far. I'm pulling my hair out!

So far my Nav Bar works perfectly, clicking the button will take you to the other pages no problem.

*However*, **I think its missing the feature of showing which page you are currently on by underlining a button or making it bold or something.**

Just wondering how you guys would go about this? I feel this is a simple concept that I'm failing to do.

Here is the Nav Bar:

```
function NavBar() {

  {/* Variable to store the name which page has just been clicked, which by default is the home page */}
  const isActive = "home";


  return (    
    <nav className="landing-page__nav-bar nav-bar">
    <ul className="nav-bar__list">
    {/* Button to Home Page */}
      <Link to ='/'><li><a data-page="home" className="home-link">
        <button href="landingpage" className={` ${isActive === "home" ? 'btn__nav-bar-btn active-link' : 'btn__nav-bar-btn'}`} onClick={() => buttonWasClicked("home")}>Home</button>
        </a></li>
      </Link>
    {/* Button to Portfolio Page */}
      <Link to ='/portfolio'><li><a data-page="portfolio" className="portfolio-link">
        <button className={` ${isActive === "portfolio" ? 'btn__nav-bar-btn active-link' : 'btn__nav-bar-btn'}`} onClick={() => buttonWasClicked("portfolio")}>Portfolio</button>
        </a></li>
        </Link>
    {/* Button to Artwork Page */}
      <Link to ='/artwork'><li><a data-page="doodles" className="doodles-link">
      <button className={` ${isActive === "artwork" ? 'btn__nav-bar-btn active-link' : 'btn__nav-bar-btn'}`} onClick={() => buttonWasClicked("artwork")}>Artwork</button>
        </a></li></Link>
      {/* Button to Photography Page */}
      <Link to ='/photography'><li><a data-page="photography" className="photography-link">
        <button className={` ${isActive === "photography" ? 'btn__nav-bar-btn active-link' : 'btn__nav-bar-btn'}`} onClick={() => buttonWasClicked("photography")}>Photography</button>
        </a></li></Link>
      {/* Button to CV Page */}
      <Link to ='/cv'><li><a data-page="cv" className="cv-link">
      <button className={` ${isActive === "cv" ? 'btn__nav-bar-btn active-link' : 'btn__nav-bar-btn'}`} onClick={() => buttonWasClicked("cv")}>CV</button
        ></a></li></Link>
      {/* Button to About Page */}
      <Link to ='/about'><li><a data-page="about" className="about-link">
      <button className={` ${isActive === "about" ? 'btn__nav-basr-btn active-link' : 'btn__nav-bar-btn'}`} onClick={() => buttonWasClicked("about")}>About</button>
        </a></li></Link>
      {/* Button to Contact Page */}
      <Link to ='/contact'><li><a data-page="contact" className="contact-link">
      <button className={` ${isActive === "contact" ? 'btn__nav-bar-btn active-link' : 'btn__nav-bar-btn'}`} onClick={() => buttonWasClicked("contact")}>Contact</button>
        </a></li></Link>     

    </ul>
  </nav>

  );
    }

export default NavBar;
```

Here is the function I was going to use within the Nav Bar to add an 'active' class to a button:

```
function ChangeActiveButton(selectedButton) {
    //What can i do here?
}

export default ChangeActiveButton;
```

Comment: Where are those `Link` components from? are you using react-router ?

Comment: You need state, from this code I suggest you read "Getting Started" section in React's docs

Comment: learning about state is definitely super important. I think another solution here is to not use state at all and get the current path from the location, provided that the component is being re-rendered due to using react-router links

Comment: @azium I do not have a router in the nav bar class but I do have a router in my App.Js. It seems strange but it works, if i remove the Link then the buttons don't work anymore

Comment: do you not have `import` or `require` statements at the top of this file? where does `Link` get imported from?

Comment: @azium oh sorry! i forgot to include my imports haha, i've imported Link and Browser Router from from react-router-dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useState` for that

In your function (before the return) write this

```
const [isActive,setActive] = useState("home")
```

You need to import `useState` from `react`
And on the button write this

```
 <button className={` ${isActive === "contact" ? 'btn__nav-bar-btn active-link' : 'btn__nav-bar-btn'}`} onClick={() => setActive("contact")}>Contact</button>
```

You can also use `NavLink` from `react-router-dom` which has a prop `activeClassName` (but this will put the class on the link not on the button)

Comment: Perfect, only a few lines of code was needed all along! Thank you so much!